# Call program from within a browser without using a webserver

Tags: python, html, browser

Is there a way to call a program (Python script) from a local HTML page?
I have a YUI-colorpicker on that page and need to send its value to a microcontroller via rs232. (There is other stuff than the picker, so I can't code an application instead of an HTML page.)

Later, this will migrate to a server, but I need a fast and easy solution now.

Thanks.

Comment: Calling a pogrom from a web browser? Would that be a Flash mob?

Comment: Ah, someone corrected the original spelling... that rather defangs the pun...

Comment: I deleted the follow up post - simply, stackoverflow doesn't work as a regular forum, and such additions often get heavily down-voted very quickly. When you have enough reputation, it is fine to leave a "thanks" in a comment to specific replies - but not as an "answer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see now that Daff mentioned the simple HTTP server, but I made an example on how you'd solve your problem (using `BaseHTTPServer`):

```
import BaseHTTPServer

HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
PORT_NUMBER = 1337

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(s):
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        s.end_headers()

        # Get parameters in query.
        params = {}
        index = s.path.rfind('?')
        if index >= 0:
            parts = s.path[index + 1:].split('&')
            for p in parts:
                try:
                    a, b = p.split('=', 2)
                    params[a] = b
                except:
                    params[p] = ''

        # !!!
        # Check if there is a color parameter and send to controller...
        if 'color' in params:
            print 'Send something to controller...'
        # !!!

        s.wfile.write('<pre>%s</pre>' % params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    httpd.server_close()
```

Now, from your JavaScript, you'd call `http://localhost:1337/?color=ffaabb`

Comment: sir. what should be the content of my html? for example. localhost/test.html

Comment: Sir . how should i run this? what should be the content of my html?

Answer (score 3):

Python has a small built in Web server. If you already already got Python to run with the RS232 you might need to read [here](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php) on how to set up a very simple and basic webserver.
An even easier one can look like [this](http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

port = 8000
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Try so separate you source as good as possible, to that you won't have too much trouble to move it to a production ready Python capable webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an an HTML page to have some sort of server-side programming then you will need a webserver of some sort to do the processing.

My suggestion would be to get a web server running on your development box, or try to accomplish what you need to do with a local desktop application or script.

Answer (score 1):

another quick solution is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3002
POW, it's a firefox extension that adds a simple web server with Server Side JS built in.

You'd be able to access a command line and call a python script from there.

Answer (score 0):

No you need some kind of server. Wh not try out the [portable webservers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=usb+web+server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)? You can run them from your usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try also XML-RPC it gives you a simple way to pass remote procedure calls from YUI towards a simple XMLRPC server and from that towards your rs232 device

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you can't setup a handler for .py/.bat/.vbs files in your browser. This should result in your chosen application running a script when you link to it. This won't work when you migrate to the server but as a testing platform it would work. Just remember to turn it off when you're done or you expose yourself to viruses from other sites.